# Json Unauthorised error in IE

Tags: json, wcf, internet-explorer

I have created a wcf webservice and I am accessing it from the browser. Following is the json request I am making.

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",
    url: podServiceUrl + "/GetTestPodItems",
    cache: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        var text = JSON.parse(msg.d);
        alert(text);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log(xhr.status);
        console.log(error);
        return;
    }
}
);
```

This is working fine in chrome and Firefox but in IE it returns an error saying unauthorized. Following is the status of xhr object

```
responseText : "{"Message":"Authentication failed.","StackTrace":null,"ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}"
status : 401
json response : System.InvalidOperationException
```

What could be the possible cause for this issue?

Comment: Can you share your service contract?

Comment: [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService] are being used

Answer (score 0):

Use json2 for a consistent cross browser implementation.